# Grouping points based of user-provided distance in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, grouping, aggregate-points

I have a point layer and I need to group/aggregate the points within a 1km proximity into 1 single point to create a new point layer.

I was trying to use Aggregate point and then Feature to point, but it eliminates the single points I have in case there are no other points in  1km proximity, but I need to be able to save those single points too. It also groups only three or more points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000) tool should do the trick. Although, be advised that Integrate will alter the original point feature class, so run this tool on a copy of the original.

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.